# clicking on an asp:hyperlink control changes all asp:hyperlinks to visited color

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I am having trouble with the color of an unvisited hyperlink changing colors when I click on a different hyperlink.  It seems that clicking on one hyperlink is changing all hyperlinks before I click on others.  My hyperlink styles are in an external stylesheet that I have referenced in my header tag.  I am using the asp:HyperLink control to simply open a modal window when clicked.  I am not going to another page.

Can someone please help me understand why the color of other unvisited hyperlinks is changing when I haven't yet clicked on those other hyperlinks?  I clear my cache each time I make a change.  One hyperlink is in an .aspx page.  The other 2 hyperlinks are in an .ascx user control.

These are my hyperlink styles:

```css
a:link {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: #bf80ff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

These are my asp hyperlink controls:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="PatriotLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="SSN Patriot Act Disclaimer" OnClick="javascript:DisplayPatDisc();return false();"></asp:HyperLink>

<asp:HyperLink ID="ACHLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="ACH Disclosure" OnClick="javascript:DisplayACHDisc();return false();"></asp:HyperLink>

<asp:HyperLink ID="eSignLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" Text="eSign Disclosure" OnClick="javascript:DisplayeSignDisc();return false();"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Thank you in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: That's because they all have the same url. In this case `#`. Make sure they are unqiue if you want to avoid your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  Please forgive my ignorance, but if I'm not navigating to a new page, what do I put for the url?  I'm simply opening a modal popup window for the user to see a paragraph of text.

Comment: It can be as simple as `#1`, `#2` etc.

Comment: That appears to have solved my problem.  I want to test more thoroughly when I get back to work on Monday, but so far so good.  Thanks again for your quick response and straight forward answer.

Comment: One last question . . . I appended some unique text to the url for each of my 3 modal popups.  I noticed that when I click on the hyperlink, that text gets appended to the url in the address bar (in this case, #eSignDisclosure):    

      http://localhost:64746/Main.aspx?SolId=10001232#eSignDisclosure

Is there a way to prevent #eSignDisclosure from showing since I'm really not navigating anywhere?

Comment: Make sure the javascript function returns `false`

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  I'm happy to mark this as answered, but I don't seem to find where to do that.

Comment: There needs to be an answer to mark it as answered. I will add one.